# Finite difference coordinate transformation for spherical polar coordinates

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, hyperbolic-pde

I have part of a  problem that is described by the momentum conservation equation:

$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\rho u \sin \theta) =0$

Where $u=f(\theta)$ and $ \rho = f(\theta,t) $ (constant velocity).

Naively one could apply one of the solutions listed [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/a-good-finite-difference-for-the-continuity-equation). The problem at hand is best described in spherical polar coordinates (thin spherical shell) and those solutions in Cartesian. **must I make some kind of coordinate transformation before discretizing this equation** or can I discretize it directly?

Secondly **is there any reason one should first expand the derivative in $\theta$** and then attempt to discretize?

As a note - I have done several of the above and have obtained solutions that do not seem to be consistent (physically a couple seem to make sense). I am interested in if there is a proper coordinate transformation that should be made or if any of the previously mentioned methods will suffice.

EDIT:

I define flux as:

$\Phi_{i+1/2} = \dfrac{u_{i+1/2}+|u_{i+1/2}|}{2}\rho_{i} \sin{\theta_{i}} 
              + \dfrac{u_{i+1/2}-|u_{i+1/2}|}{2}\rho_{i+1} \sin{\theta_{i+1}} $

$\Phi_{i-1/2} = \dfrac{u_{i-1/2}+|u_{i-1/2}|}{2}\rho_{i-1} \sin{\theta_{i-1}}
              + \dfrac{u_{i-1/2}-|u_{i-1/2}|}{2}\rho_{i} \sin{\theta_{i}}$

I'm guessing the 'proper' way to define the flux would be to evaluate $\sin{\theta}$ at the $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ 'cell boundaries' rather than at the cell center. This would be more in line with the definition of flux.

One final question - what should I do at the boundaries ($\theta = 0 $ is particularly a problem and I just avoid that point altogether).

Comment: I don't see $h$ in your equation. Please correct _sin\theta_ ($sin\theta$) in _\sin\theta_ ($\sin\theta$): proper math formatting matters!

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason you have to transform the coordinates before discretizing the equation.  However, since you are using spherical coordinates, you will end up with a non-linear system rather than the linear system that would appear in cartesian coordinates.  If you want to work with a linear system, you will have to do variable transformations (much like the creation of $\Phi$ that appears in the first answer of your linked question).

As far as expanding the derivative in $\theta$, I would recommend not to, unless you must for the above transformations.  The equation in its current state is in the conservative form, with all $u$'s being coupled with $\rho$.  When you expand the derivative you will lose this coupling.  The two solutions will converge to each other with finer and finer meshes, however there is a non-zero difference between them.  Also, someone else with more experience may be able to elaborate on the advantage/disadvantages of the two forms, since even though it is called the conservative form of the equation, finite difference methods are, by their nature, non-conservative on some level.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have investigated possible solutions to this problem but have yet to find a solution that seems reasonable. I have the BC's down - but no benchmarks to test my scheme against.

Comment: what was your thinking behind the formulation of $\Phi$?  It seems that you are choosing your index on $\rho\sin(\theta)$ based on the sign of $u$.  Is this for stability?